# Apply a command to all subdirectories/files

Tags: bash, directory, command

In a parent directory, I have several sub-directories, each of them contain one or more space-delimited text files.

I have the following command that outputs what I want, but only for an individual file `INPUTFILE.txt`

```
awk '{if (NF>4){print $1, $2, $3 , "0" } else {print $0}}' INPUTFILE.txt
```

Considering the fact that I have thousands sub-directories, and the file names will vary, how can I apply this command to all sub-directories; from the parent directory?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by `each of them enclose a table`. Do you mean every directory contains a tab-delimited file? 2. In each directory is there always only one file, and always named `INPUTFILE.txt` or could there be one or more files with a variety of file names?

Comment: @user454038 There is just one ascii table (with space delimiter) in each sub-directories. And yes each table has a different name (that´s the point of my question) accordingly with the sub-directory name.

Comment: Apparently, the edition by @user454038, introduces contradictions! (one or more vs one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `cd` to your desired parent directory.

Then, make use of the `find` to run your `awk` command:

```
find -type f -exec awk '{if (NF>4){print $1, $2, $3 , "0" } else {print $0}}' {} +
```

### Explanation

- it is already recursive by default so it will carry this out for all sub-directories
- `-type f` will limit to finding `f`iles , instead of both files and directories
- the `-exec somecommand {} +` syntax runs a command, and puts the file paths found where you write `{}`
- the `+` option has been said to be more efficient because it only runs one instance of `awk` while putting the find results as arguments in `{}` whereas the other way of running it (not shown here) would run awk once per each file name and is said to be less efficient

Answer (score 1):

Ok The quick and dirty way to do this is with a loop but we need to set some things up first. The following will give you a text file with names and paths of the files on which you wish to run the awk command.You will need to run it from the parent directory.

```
find . -type f -print >> source.txt
```

Then you run the loop

```
for i in $(cat source.txt); do 
  awk '{if (NF>4){print $1, $2, $3 , "0" } else {print $0}}' $i >> OUTPUTFILE.txt
done
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted a single output file of if you wanted multiple output files.

If you want multiple output files you can do this:

```
for i in $(cat source.txt); do 
  awk '{if (NF>4){print $1, $2, $3 , "0" } else {print $0}}' $i >> $i.processed.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: The question changed after the answer was written...

```
for a in */INPUTFILE.txt
do 
   cp "$a" "$a.bak" 
   YOUR-AWK "$a.bak" > "$a" 
done
```

The new question looks strange!!
If I understand it correctly

```
YOUR-AWK */*.txt > output.txt
```